# Connect USB printer to an ethernet-only router

Tags: router, usb, printer, openwrt, cups

I have a XIAOMI Mi Router 4A Gigabit router and it is OpenWRT compatible. I was thinking of hooking up my Canon PIXMA E410 printer (which only has USB) to the router and setup a print server (p910nd/CUPS).

The problem is, the router does not have a USB port. So is it possible to maybe purchase a USB to Ethernet adapter for this?

Another option is to use a Pi Zero (which will of course work), but that would be more costly.

Comment: USB ethernet adapter exist, but only to provide ethernet to a device with computing resources like a laptop.  Your printer doesn't have the software to lease an IP address, and do all the other things required to use TCP/IP.  If it did you would have a network printer with wifi or Ethernet jack and your problems would be solved.

Comment: Also any Ethernet to USB adapter is going to cost MORE than a Pi Zero, or even a Pi 4.  So you would have to reverse engineer the printer's firmware to add a printer server with tcp/ip support.  Most printers don't have big enough firmware, thus you would have to add a chip with large firmware.  So a project which you could complete in a few days would now takes years of reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

**(A)** USB Print Servers are readily available for what you want.

The Printer attaches to the Print Server.

The Print Server is on the network, so you can install Print Drivers on any computer you wish to use for printing.

Here is an example Print Server.

[USB Print Server](https://www.amazon.ca/IOGEAR-Server-1-Port-GPSU21-Silver/dp/B000FW60FW/ref=asc_df_B000FW60FW/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292901645034&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8983908661570988640&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1002350&hvtargid=pla-547533053887&th=1)

.

**(B)** To support all functions (print, scan, possibly Air Print) you might be better off to get a printer with an included Ethernet port. My Printer here connects on Ethernet and supports scanning.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know about commercial USB print servers. But I would rather avoid it since it does not get regularly updated (maybe never now) making them obsolete. Also, most commercial print servers do not support scanning. But with OpenWRT, SANE is configurable.

Comment: The only other approach (not something I like) is to hook the Printer to a Computer by USB and then share it out. I do not know if sharing supports scanning either.  You may wish to consider a new printer with an Ethernet port. That works for certain.

Comment: @Lugman Some kind of SBC like a raspberry Pi is going to be the only option that allows you under the hood access to upgrade and configure ALL the software.

Comment: USB printservers ONLY work with supported printers. Most manufacturers supply a list. If there isn't one, don't be tempted to buy it.